# RSS Feed iPhone using Storyboard iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, rss, storyboard

I am wondering if there are any tutorials for RSS Feeds on the iPhone using Storyboard for iOS 5? Rey Wenderlich has a great tutorial creating a RSS Feed on the iPhone - found here: [RSS Feed Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2636/how-to-make-a-simple-rss-reader-iphone-app-tutorial)

However, I am unsure how I can use this tutorial when using storyboard. I have been unsuccessful in finding a RSS tutorial for the iPhone using Storyboard too.

If anyone came across one, please can you let me know?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently had difficulty finding a similar tutorial, and ended up creating my own simple RSS reader using the MWFeedParser library: https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser coupled with a UITableView.

Once I was able to get a list of the blog entries, I created a Core Data object for each of my blog entries, with help from this tutorial: http://maybelost.com/2011/12/tutorial-storyboard-app-with-core-data/

These entries are loaded into a UITableView in my app, which displays the content of the post when the user selects the row in the Table View.

You can use the storyboarding technique to do this, by dragging the UITableView onto the Storyboard and sub-classing the UITableViewController to implement the feed parsing.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @WoolyWonder - I am wondering if you know how to bypass the ARC and ASIHTTPRequest issue found in the RSS Feed Tutorial in my original post. As I am using Xcode 4.3.1 and iOS 5, I think the tutorial only caters for Xcode 3ish, because it does not come across the ARC issue...

Comment: ASIHTTPRequest is no longer actively being maintained, so I switched to AFNetworking, which, while a little more verbose seems to be working okay.If you definitely want to stick with ASIHTTPRequest but want to keep arc enabled, then navigate to the project build phases, and expand the Compile Sources dropdown. For each ASI file, double click on the compiler flags column and add the "-fno-objc-arc" option. See this answer for screenshots: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project